# List of functions disallowing passing null to parameter

Tags: php, php-8.1

I am starting my upgrades to PHP 8.1, and one of the issues that I'm running into is the *Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated*.  (see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70574048/passing-null-to-non-nullable-internal-function-parameters-updating-existing-co) and the [problematic RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_null_to_scalar_internal_arg))

For example, by default all my database results are run through `htmlspecialchars()`, which will lead to a problem if that field is `null`, as illustrated here:

```
php > $foo = null;
php > echo htmlspecialchars($foo);
PHP Deprecated:  htmlspecialchars(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in php shell code on line 1

Deprecated: htmlspecialchars(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in php shell code on line 1
php >
```

Since legacy code relied on duck typing, this could crop up *anywhere*, with who-knows-how-many functions. I will have to manually search through all the legacy code to find the instances where a `null` ***MIGHT*** be evaluated.

So far, I have not been able to find a list of the internal functions that have been <s>broken</s> fixed. Can anybody point me to a list of these functions?

Comment: See [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/allow_null) which also includes a list of functions

Comment: Yikes, that's quite a list.  Thanks :) Maybe there's room for a little grace in the duck typing.  I was wondering why they didn't define them as (?string:string)...

Comment: I agree that this will be a pain for some legacy code, but luckily these are just deprecations, and hopefully you have a tool that can help you. The discussion actually started [two years ago](https://externals.io/message/105845). I'm personally not a big fan of the change, but I also get it. `strlen` should be used with strings. If you pass `null` to it, you aren't passing a "null string", you are just passing `null`. In user-land code, we can choose to be lax about this, but from the framework we want consistency.

Comment: You can use Psalm. It will tell you all the places where a nullable type is passed to a string parameter.