# Error message: Deprecated Functionality: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack)

Tags: php, strpos

Since a upgrade to PHP 8.1 from 7.4 we are getting this error in an application:

```
Error message: Deprecated Functionality: strpos(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($haystack) of type string is deprecated in /Model/Plugin/Order.php on line 33
```

Line 33 is a IF-statement

```
33. if (strpos($orderStatus, '_') !== false) {
34. do stuff...
35. }
```

Is it possible to change it in someway to be able to handle null values?

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing null to non-nullable internal function parameters - Updating Existing Code Base to php 8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70574048/passing-null-to-non-nullable-internal-function-parameters-updating-existing-co)

Comment: `if ( $orderStatus != null ) { if( strpos($orderStatus, '_') !== false) { //do stuff } }`